# Error while Running MIDP 2 applications in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midp-2.0

I am trying to run(emulate) a simple midp2 j2me application in netbeans(6.8) in ubuntu 10.04. It is building fine , with no errors, but when i choose run , it  gives "http server is not running.start it first" error.
I am able to successfully build and run it using  the java wireless toolkit. But  using Netbeans would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Mobility plugin in Netbeans 6.8 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your coding u make use of server/servlet,etc.So before executing ur application run the server then execute the application .Then it works.